# How to make an https request in c?

Tags: c, https, openssl

I have been trying to make an https request in c using openssl. However for some reason openssl gives me a segmentation fault. I am not sure what exactly is going on, but `SSL_read` and `SSL_free` give me a segmentation fault.

I have setup a struct to work a bit like a class, that holds all the information about the connection.

**https.h**

```
struct sock {
  char ip[20];
  int socket;
  char lastcmd[1024];
  int loop;
  SSL *conn;
  int port;
};


int connect_sock(struct sock s) {
    s.socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(s.socket == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(s.ip);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( s.port );
    if (connect(s.socket , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    SSL_load_error_strings ();
    SSL_library_init ();
    SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx; = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_client_method ());
    s.conn = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(s.conn, s.socket);
    return 1;
}

int read_sock(struct sock s,size_t length) {
    s.lastcmd[length*2];
    if(SSL_read(s.conn, s.lastcmd,length) <0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void close_sock(struct sock s) {
    SSL_shutdown(s.conn);
    close(s.socket);
}
```

I call upon the above code like this

**main.c**

```
int main() {
    struct sock s;
    hostname_to_ip("www.google.com",s.ip);
    printf("%s\n",s.ip);
    s.port = 443;
    if(connect_sock(s)==1) {
        printf("Connected to %s\n",s.ip);
        read_sock(s,1024);
        printf("%s\n",s.lastcmd);
        close_sock(s);
    }
}
```

So the output is like this

```
ip.ip.ip.ip
Connected to ip.ip.ip.ip
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Although the main.c given above attempts to read when it produces the segfault, even doing an `SSL_free` or `SSL_shutdown` on it causes a segfault

Compiler info:

gcc main.c -lssl -lcrypto -o main

Comment: you can use curl for C, check it here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html

Comment: @nikomaster This works for https as well?

Comment: test it, you can check the main page of examples: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Comment: being honest, i've never tasted in https but yes in http.

Comment: Also see [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. It makes an HTTPS request in C. You should pobably add symbols to your program: `gcc -g3 -O0 main.c -o main -lssl -lcrypto`. Then, run it under Valgrind. Valgrind will likely tell you where the problem is.